# How can I access interior XML tags?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML file:

```
<ChangeInfo >
    <Overview name="UML1"  >
        <Property name="actor1" value="1"  />
        <Overview name="UML2"  >
            <Property name="actor2" value="2"  />      
        </Overview>  
    </Overview>
</ChangeInfo>
```

and I tried the following C# Code to reach all nested nodes inside the main node:
I want to access `<Overview name="UML2">` and its children.

My code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\xxml\xxml\xml_file\uml.xml");
XmlNode targets = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ChangeInfo/Overview");
IEnumerator s = targetlist.GetEnumerator();
while (s.MoveNext())
{
    XmlNode x = (XmlNode)(s.Current);
    XmlNodeList  ch = x.ChildNodes;

    for (int i = 0; i < ch.Count; i++)
    {
        String att = "";
        if (ch[i].Attributes != null)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ch[i].Attributes.Count; j++)
            {
                att += "    "+ch[i].Attributes[j].Name + " " + ch[i].Attributes[j].Value;
            }
            textBox1.Text += "\r\n" + att ;
        }
    }
}
```

but I am still unable to access `<Overview name="UML2"  >` and its child `<Property name="actor2" value="2"  />`.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Loren is correct.

But today's modern .net has a simpler way.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\xxml\xxml\xml_file\uml.xml");
var element = document.XPathSelectElement("//Overview[@name='UML2']");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no C# person, but I googled 'c# xpath' and found the following page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

You can use the following XPath to get to the XmlNode that you need:

```
//Overview[@name/string() = 'UML2']
```

:

```
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathDocument docNav;
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
String strExpression;
// Open the XML.
docNav = new XPathDocument(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\xxml\xxml\xml_file\uml.xml");
 // Create a navigator to query with XPath.
 nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
strExpression = "//Overview[@name/string() = 'UML2']";
NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);
```

I hope that this helps.